# How to do view transition like setting of system iOS?

Tags: ios, swift, uitapgesturerecognizer, uiviewanimationtransition

I have a problem and I have no idea for that...

I want change interface like setting:[settings.gif](http://www.raywenderlich.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/07/settings.gif)

I do not know even the key word to search it in the internet...

I used "interactive transition" and "gesture interactive" etc... but I can not find a right answer or demo or code...

Could you tell me how to code to change interface like settings of system iOS (a tutorial perhaps...)? Thank you very much !

PS : I created the two views by uiviewcontroller, not uinavigationController

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have fund my answer, I push it there, because I think this perhaps will help other beginners.

1) I embedded in a navigation bar for a view.

2) after 1), we can use

```
let secondViewController = self.storyboard!.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("Your view") as! LoginViewController

        self.navigationController!.pushViewController(secondViewController, animated: true)
```

3) In the seconde view, there will have a backbitten automatic, and we can do like settings of system iOS

Answer (score 0):

It is called `interactivePopGestureRecognizer`

`self.navigationController?.interactivePopGestureRecognizer?.delegate = self`

 `self.navigationController?.interactivePopGestureRecognizer?.enabled = true`

put that lines in your ViewController class and add `UIGestureRecognizerDelegate` to your class

```
class ViewControllerClass : UIViewController, UIGestureRecognizerDelegate {
// class methods
}
```

You can also implement delegate methods

```
func gestureRecognizer(gestureRecognizer: UIGestureRecognizer, shouldRecognizeSimultaneouslyWithGestureRecognizer otherGestureRecognizer: UIGestureRecognizer) -> Bool {
    return true
}

func gestureRecognizer(gestureRecognizer: UIGestureRecognizer, shouldBeRequiredToFailByGestureRecognizer otherGestureRecognizer: UIGestureRecognizer) -> Bool {
    return (gestureRecognizer is UIScreenEdgePanGestureRecognizer)
}
```

Comment: Thank you for you answer, I have two view : `class ViewController: UIViewController, UITextFieldDelegate, UITextViewDelegate` and `class LoginViewController: UIViewController, UITextFieldDelegate,UIGestureRecognizerDelegate`, there is a button in the `class ViewController` to show `class LoginViewController`, I did like you said : I added your code in the class `class LoginViewController`, but it does not works...

Comment: First, check if your navigationController is not nil and try to add this line         `self.navigationController?.interactivePopGestureRecognizer?.enabled = true
`  default is true, but add it to make sure it's all OK. Also it would be nice if you provide your code with these two controllers

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I do not how to check navigationController is null or not...but I think it is null, because the two view are `UIViewController`, and I never define a navigationController in class by code...I just add a navigationController in the XIB...So what I should do ? Thank you. I tried your code, it does not work...I think because navigationController is null, how to give a value to navigationController in the class `UIViewController` ? Thank you

Comment: I created the two view by uiviewcontroller, not uinavigationController lol

Comment: To achieve this effect you need UINavigationController with UIViewController

Comment: I have used  UINavigationController to show another view, but I want to I can do like settings of system iOS from second view to first view, not only by a button back, Could you give me some help ? I think it is not easy, because I have searched it on internet, but I can not find a right answer, on internet, they all use `UIPercentDrivenInteractiveTransition` not `UIViewController`...